# Adding Text to a File with an Enum

Tags: c#, visual-studio, enums

I am having trouble trying to call my class object so i can display the enum and the message that will follow. I have all of the code completed for the class(i think), but am having trouble in the static void main. How can i add the Enum as an argument in the tWrite method. i am know there is something wrong with my code, i just do not know where it is. Here is my current code:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.IO;

namespace Logging
{
public class Log
{
    public enum Levels { Debug, Warn, Info, Error};

    private string path = @"C:\Users\eliotta1130\Desktop\CSharp\Labs\Logging.txt";

    //public string Path { get; set; }
    //public Levels Levels { get; set; }

    public Log(string path)
    {
        this.path = path;
        if(!File.Exists(path))
        {
            File.Create(path);
        }
        StreamWriter textOut = new StreamWriter( new FileStream(
                                                path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write));
        textOut.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);

        textOut.Close();
    }
    public void tWrite(Levels levels, string message)
    {
        StreamWriter fs = new StreamWriter( new FileStream(path, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write));
        fs.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}, {1}", DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.ffff")), message);
        fs.Close();
    }

}
}
```

Here is where i am trying to call the class object.

```
namespace Logging
{
class Logging
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Log files = new Log("Logging.txt");

        files.tWrite( , "Fix the problem");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You don't seem to use the Enums level anywhere. Why are you bothering to put it in the declaration of tWrite?

Comment: i am not getting any errors because of that, but i am getting an error in the tWrite method for some reason. it is not writing anything to a file. does anything look wrong in there? this is what it says "Additional information: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list" and it highlights the fs.WriteLine in the tWrite method.@GrantWinney

Comment: ah, didn't see that. thank you. it is not creating the file now? it runs successfully, but the file is not being created? i am unsure where my code is throwing it off? @GrantWinney

Comment: the path is fine and i tried that and still didnt work. hmm... the txt file doesnt exist which is why i have that if statement to create the file, but i am not sure why it is not creating the file. @GrantWinney

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the enumeration inside the other class, so you can call it like this:

```
files.tWrite(Log.Levels.Warn, "Fix the problem");
```

Or move it outside of the class, but keep it in the same namespace, and call it like this:

```
files.tWrite(Levels.Warn, "Fix the problem");
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach to Grant's answer is to define an instance of the enum in your Log class:

```
 public Levels LogLevel {get;set;}

 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
    Log files = new Log("Logging.txt");
    files.LogLevel = Log.Levels.Warn;
    files.tWrite("Fix the problem");
 }
```

Of course, you need modify your tWrite() signature accordingly, but this is not the focus.